# Como fazer deploy de Angular e Java no Heroku?

Tags: java, angularjs, node.js, heroku

Tenho uma aplicação web em AngularJS que se comunica com um backend em Java. Gostaria de uma hospedagem e acabei vendo sobre o Heroku. Há possibilidade de eu comprar um único plano (por exemplo o de $7) e hospedar as duas aplicações? Ou terei que comprar como se fossem duas hospedagem para armazenar separadamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite Rodrigo, a hospedagem tem que ser para a Java, levando em consideração que você vai gerar um arquivo .WAR, e esse arquivo conterá tanto o código java com o angular.

Comment: Entendi, perfeito. Mesmo tendo dependências do node, eu compilo o front e "armazeno" juntamente com o projeto Java para depois gerar um único .war? Obrigado.

Comment: Qual framework você está utilizando no back? E qual versão do java você está usando?

Comment: Por enquanto só uso o spring-boot e o Java 8. Vi alguns frameworks que podem fazer esta integração, mas não cheguei a testar ainda.

Comment: Mas qual a versão do angular? é o 2?

Comment: Ah sim, é o 1.4

Comment: tenta esse link, que mostra como utilizar o angular mais o spring:
http://javasampleapproach.com/spring-framework/spring-boot/configure-angularjs-springboot

Comment: Muito obrigado. Só de descobrir que há possibilidade de integrar as duas aplicações já ajudou muito.